# Python NumPy: How to fill a matrix using an equation

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I wish to initialise a matrix `A`, using the equation `A_i,j = f(i,j)` for some `f` (It's not important what this is).

How can I do so concisely avoiding a situation where I have two for loops?

Answer (score 12):

[numpy.fromfunction](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html#numpy.fromfunction) fits the bill here.

Example from doc:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: i + j, (3, 3), dtype=int)
array([[0, 1, 2],
   [1, 2, 3],
   [2, 3, 4]])
```

Comment: Warning: the documentation does not explain this clearly, but `np.fromfunction(f, shape, dtype=dtype)` is a thin wrapper around `f(*np.indices(shape, dtype=dtype))`. It does not perform an individual call to `f` for each cell, so if you pass it a function that doesn't work in a vectorized manner, you'll get weird and erroneous results.

Answer (score 2):

One could also get the indexes of your array with `numpy.indices` and then apply the function `f` in a vectorized fashion,

```
import numpy as np

shape = 1000, 1000

Xi, Yj = np.indices(shape)

A = (2*Xi + 3*Yj).astype(np.int) # or any other function f(Xi, Yj)
```